# count records in MYSQL table before certain spot

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a simple 2 column table in mysql: col1=SEX and col2=NAME

I want to find out how many records (count) exist PRIOR to a particular record.  In pseudo-mysql:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) BEFORE WHERE SEX="M" AND NAME="BOB" SORT BY NAME
```

Assuming there is only one BOB, and lots of Male and Female records.

How can I count how many records meet the criteria PRIOR to the chosen record?

Comment: Is there a timestamp on the table?  If not, I think you're out of luck.  How do you know something comes before Bob?

Comment: i think he means alphabetic considering there are only 2 columns

Comment: Sort by?   Do you mean Order by?

Comment: Your column would be better named as Gender instead. In relational database theory (and hence in practice) there's no such thing as a record before or after, unless you have a column to sort on. Otherwise all record selections are treated like instanteniously created data sets. By the way there is no before or after, what exists is what you select.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select count(*)
from table
where rownum < (select rownum
                from table
                where SEX='M' 
                AND NAME='BOB' LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM datable WHERE SEX="M" AND NAME<="BOB";
```